# Get last Month of selected check boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, date

I have a for loop that check whether some checkboxes are checked

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        //Some code here
    }
}
```

There are 12 checkboxes, 1 for each month.

What i want is to calculate the number of days between a variable StartDate and the last month. It's hard to explain sorry.

For example, `StartDate = 1st September 2010`, Checked Boxes are April, October and December.

The result should be the days between 01/09/2010 and 01/04/2011.

If StartDate = 1st November 2010 then the result would be the days between 01/11/2010 and 01/10/2011.

I'm think I struggling because the loop goes from jan to dec. If it was started from the startdate month I'd be OK.

Please ask some questions if i need to explain more.

Comment: I don't understand how you're doing it between 2 dates when you are selecting more than 2 months??

Comment: If I understand correctly: From the start date I take a calendar, go through the months forward - possibly into the next year - and I stop when I get to a month for which the name has been ticked in the list of checkboxes. Then I calculate the number of days between the start date and that month. Problem: if that is true, I understand your first example but not the second. I'd expect the second example to calculate the days from 1st Nov 2010 to 01 Apr 2011 (since April is checked, too). Please clarify as maybe I didn't fully understand the algorithm.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't explain it clearly. In the second example i should be from the startdate to october because oct is after april but before nov(startdate). Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @w69rdy - The only month that i'm interested in in the latest month. The other ones are used in some different code, which is working.

Comment: ............... (comment deleted)

Comment: What kind of checkboxes? WinForms? WebForms?

Comment: @Ash: it matters, so you should always include that in your tags.

Comment: @John - I never said it didn't matter?

Comment: @Ash: you implied that by leaving it out of your tags.

Comment: @John - I doubt the question could be answered any differently whether I added the tag or not.

Comment: @Ash: Yes, I suppose the `CheckBox` controls of every UI technology must have the same properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are olny interested in the DateTime logic, this should do:

```
private static TimeSpan GetLatestSpan(IEnumerable<int> monthNumbers, DateTime startDate)
{
  var candidateDates = monthNumbers
                    .Select(month => GetNearestDateInDifferentMonthWithSameDay(startDate, month));

  return candidateDates.Max() - startDate;
}

private static DateTime GetNearestDateInDifferentMonthWithSameDay(DateTime startDate, int month)
{
 return new DateTime(month > startDate.Month ? startDate.Year : startDate.Year + 1, month, startDate.Day);
}
```

Using your example,

```
var checkedMonthNumbers = new List<int>();

foreach (CheckBox chk in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
       {
         if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    checkedMonthNumbers.Add(GetMonthNumberFromCheckBox(chk));
                }
       }

MessageBox.Show("Required timespan is " + GetLatestSpan(checkedMonthNumbers, StartDate));
```

EDIT:

Note that I would probably rewrite the loop as:

```
var checkedMonthNumbers = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                                  .Where(chk => ck.Checked)
                                  .Select(chk => GetMonthNumberFromCheckBox(chk));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num=0,currentyear=2010;
for(i=startmonth;i<endmonth;i++)
{
if(i=13)
{
i=1;
currentyear++
}
num+=datetime.daysinmonth(currentyear,i);
}
```

i think that it will work for you

Comment: I know how to calculate the difference between the months. The problem is working out which is the endmonth.

Answer (score 0):

- Search the selected months for the
  nearest *preceding* month to startDate. So basically just search only preceding months.
- If there is none, pick the last month
  from the list.